# What's wrong with my methodology for applying an attribute to all element children of a node?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently transitioning a web-app from using jQuery to pure Javascript and think I have run into a problem with my understanding of Javascript.

I'm attempting to apply an attribute to all of the child elements of an unordered list, my code looks like this:

```js
function openDropdown(elmnt) {
  console.log("dropdown menu clicked!");
  let listItems = elmnt.children
  let firstListItem = elmnt.firstElementChild
  console.log(listItems);
  console.log(firstListItem);
  if (firstListItem.style.display !== "none") {
    listItems.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    listItems.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
ul {}

ul li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-items">
  <ul class="dropdown" onclick="openDropdown(this)">Title of UL
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As I understand it the function openDropdown should:

1. Check to see if the first li has is display: none
2. If it doesn't, assign it display: none
3. If it does, assign it display: block

The console logs both `elmnt.children` and `firstElementChild` correctly, but I get the error `cannot set property 'display' of undefined` I'm assuming that I'm using the property .children incorrectly but I can't figure out how to fix this function. How would I go about making this function work?

Comment: A `<ul>` directly inside of a `<ul>` doesn't make sense

Comment: And you cannot use a list of elements to set properties of each item; you have to do the iteration through the list yourself.

Comment: good catch @Pointy that was supposed to be a div

Comment: `listItems` does not have a `.style` property. It's a collection, but only individual elements (such as `firstListItem`) have styles. You need a loop. The duplicate I've chosen is about dom selection methods (and probably useful if you're transitioning from jQuery, which doesn't distinguish single elements, always keeping a collection) but the issue and solution are the same for `.children`.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks very much, that's it.